# reliable place to register .kr domains

Tags: domains

can someone direct me to a reliable place to buy .kr domains?

I have found some places but not sure I should register it in hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a citizen of South Korea or business located in South Korea? If not you can't get one as those are the requirements for registration. A copy of your company registration in Korea with proof of company address in both English and Korean languages is required for registration.

But if you are a citizen of South Korea or have a business located there then you can register [here](http://www.101domain.com/kr.htm) or [here](http://www.asiaregistry.com/domains/domains_kr.html).

Comment: really :s I was thinking to get one for my personal url shortener app. I guess I am out of luck here. thanks.

Comment: @tugberk: I think at the 2nd link provided by John you can register .kr domains cause they say `Or we can act as your agent for free`. I'm quite sure it works cause I had the same issue with German domains .DE (they have similar restrictions) but the same domain provider Instra on http://www.europeregistry.com/ acted as agent.